# how to integrate bootstrap template to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

how can I integrate bootstrap bottom section into wordpress theme. When I use widget, it doesn't show correctly because it has some style which are not included into widget. I mean I implement sth like this and doesn't show correctly.
below is static html.

```
<section id="bottom">
    <div class="container wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="widget">
                    <h3>Company</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">We are hiring</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Meet the team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Copyright</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms of use</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>    
            </div><!--/.col-md-3-->
        </div>
    </div>
</section><!--/#bottom-->
```

and here is in function.php

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'bottom',
    'before_widget' => '<h3>',
    'after_widget' => '</h3>',
    'before_title' => '<ul>',
    'after_title' => '</ul>',
));
?>
```

finally here is inside my page.

```
<?php
<section id="bottom">
    <div class="container wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="widget">
                    <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('bottom')) : ?><?php endif; ?>
                </div>    
            </div><!--/.col-md-3-->
        </div>
    </div>
</section><!--/#bottom-->
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, lets see how this works :

### Register sidebar

To register a new sidebar on WordPress, it is recommended to include an ID for that sidebar.

> If you do not set the id argument value, you will get E_USER_NOTICE
>   messages in debug mode, starting with version 4.2.

More details about on this link :
[Function Reference/register sidebar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar).

And at the same time, we will use the ID to call our registered sidebar. Here i include an example.

```
// Register Sidebars
function custom_sidebars() {

    $args = array(
        'id'            => 'bottom',
        'name'          => __( 'Bottom Sidebar', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'   => __( 'My bottom sidebar', 'text_domain' ),
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</li>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    );
    register_sidebar( $args );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_sidebars' );
```

Normally inserted in `functions.php` file of active theme.
If you want, you can customize title and list HTML tags with your theme design.

### How to call sidebar

Then, when we want call it, in your case i think the file is `footer.php`, we will do it preferably in an if statement, as follows :

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'bottom' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'bottom' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #secondary -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

In your template, it should look like :

```
<section id="bottom">
    <div class="container wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'bottom' ) ) : ?>
                    <div class="widget">
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'bottom' ); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div><!--/.col-md-3-->
        </div>
    </div>
</section><!--/#bottom-->
```

We can call the sidebar by id or name, or even number to check.

I hope this help you to understand and solve your case.

Comment: this doesn't work. because it doesn't compatible with my style. As I wrote , I need `<li><a href='localhost/.....>text</a></li>` inside `<ul>` tag.